# Capybara Find Within Synchronize Not Waiting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

The code below keeps looping, where I would expect find to wait for its default wait time of 2 seconds before throwing an exception and having the loop iterate.

```
user_general.synchronize(10) do
    tab_me.primary_action("Plus").click
    add_edit_item.find('.ready[data-id="pageAddEditItems"]')
end
```

Comment: Sleep does nothing for 2 seconds. Find should keep trying to find the element for the default wait time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Capybara only the outermost synchronize loop is rerun on failures, you can see this in the source code for #synchronize which does the following

```
if session.synchronized
  yield  # if we are already in a synchronize loop just run the code
else
  ...   # catch errors and retry until max wait time expires or success
end
```